# What's the shortcut of select a function code in VSCode on MacOS?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

It is common to use `shift+down` to select a function code, I want a more efficient way to select function like below pic. Thanks for help.

My VSCode version and other info:

```
Version: 1.37.1
Submit: f06011ac164ae4dc8e753a3fe7f9549844d15e35
Date: 2019-08-15T16:16:34.800Z
Electron: 4.2.7
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 18.6.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. collapse the function (space after the line number with the **`def`**)
2. select the whole line
3. remove the collapse
4. copy the selection (<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>)